# Is it possible to have multiple Safari windows with different proxy settings?

Tags: safari, proxy

I'd like to have a Safari window that routes all its traffic through a custom proxy for debugging, while the rest of the traffic on my machine uses the normal system-level proxy settings. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Safari only supports using the system-wide proxies configured in System Preferences. There may be a Safari extension out there that supports this feature, but I haven't heard of one.

If you don't have to absolutely have to use Safari, Firefox allows for configuring a proxy independent of the system-wide one.